# Sizing divs to fit page and figuring overflow scroll without specified height

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with element sizing on my page.

I have a column with several sections inside. The whole column has max-width set to 80vh. Inside that column there are:

First is `#profilePic`, which height (and width) is automatically resized according to page width.
Second is `#profileInfo` section, which has following subsections:

First Sub. is `#profileName` with fixed height.
Second Sub. is `#profileAbout` which I want to have filled up the remaining space in `#profileInfo` section. If the content of that section won't fit (and overflows), I want it to be scrollable.
The third Sub. is `#profileEmail` with fixed height.

Now, since I don't know the height of `#profileInfo` (because of the auto-resizing profile picture), I am unable to set the max-height parameter of `#profileAbout` thus, the `overflow-y: auto;` is unable to apply, and so the content of the whole column just overflows from it.

To sum it up, I'm just trying to make the column as short as possible (when there is little 'about' content) but make it reach at max the bottom of the screen (that's where the max-height of 80vh comes from) and make the rest of the content be scrollable.

```
<div id="profileLeftPanel" class="card col-md-3">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Profile pic -->
    <div id="profilePic">
      <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION["someUser"]["profile_pic"] ?>" alt="[profile_pic]">
    </div>

    <div id="profileInfo">

      <!-- Name -->
      <h4 id="profileName"><?php echo $_SESSION["someUser"]["name"] ?></h4>

      <!-- About -->
      <div id="profileAbout">
        <?php echo $_SESSION["someUser"]["about"] ?>
      </div>

      <!-- Email address -->
      <div id="profileEmail"><?php echo $_SESSION["someUser"]["email"] ?></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of how it looks like, and what are the cases I want to solve: https://jsfiddle.net/mjnoach/zo32ra4f/

Comment: Can you include an example as a working snippet, it would be easier for us to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sure. https://jsfiddle.net/muwu667s/1/ Here are two cases that needs solving out. On the left, the `#profileAbout` (yellow) should first expand to fill the rest of the page (white space), and only then should it activate scrolling, if there is still more text to display. On the right, there is little content inside, so the whole column should shrink just enough to display the content and no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick and dirty suggestion:

```
#profileAbout {
  ...
  height: 100%;
  max-height: calc( 500px - 150px - 40px - 40px );
  /* Subtract the heights of the other elements on the page. */
  ...
}
```

With your additional information, here is another solution, using flexbox layout.

```
<style>
    .row {
        background-color: white;
        width: 200px;
        height: 500px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #profilePic {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
    #profilePic img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    #profileInfo {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #profileName {
        background-color: blueviolet;
        margin: 0;
        flex: 0 0 40px;
    }
    #profileAbout {
        background-color: yellow;
        overflow-y: auto;
        flex: 0 1 auto;
    }
    #profileEmail {
        background-color: blue;
        flex: 0 0 40px;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div id="profilePic">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div id="profileInfo">
        <h4 id="profileName"></h4>
        <div id="profileAbout">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus, nesciunt?
        </div>
        <div id="profileEmail"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To test the behavior, you can

- change the height of `.row`
- change the placeholder image in `#profilePic`

Comment: I would have done it already, but the problem is that the `#profilePic` height is not constant. It is resizable and dependent on the viewport size.

Comment: With that additional information, I updated my answer with another possible solution.